# PHP array in javascript json_encode not working

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have a php page that connects to mysql database, performs a query, stores its result as an array as a session variable.

```
$_SESSION['array1']=$array1;
```

This variable is received by another php page within same directory like this:

```
session_start();
$array1= $_SESSION['array1'];
```

Now, in the same php page itself, I have a javascript code that intends to access this $array1 and print its value. I found similar questions online and got to know about json_encode function but couldn't get it done. Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var jsarray= <?php json_encode($array1); ?>;
document.write (jsarray[2]);   </script>
```

I am just trying to print the 2nd index of array through javascript but haven't been able to do so. Nothing is displayed at all. I can see that I can print array on the second page using php but I need javascript code to be able to access the array. 
If I provide values to jsaraay in javascript code like:

```
var jsarray=[1,2,3,4,5];
```

and i print 2nd index,

```
document.write(jsarray[2]);
```

The output is correct. I want to access php array the same way. Please help?

Comment: `$_SESSION['array1'][2]` isn't working for you?

Comment: Have you tried turning the data into JSON using json_encode?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Try json_encode($array1);

Comment: Try JSON.prase() on your js var.

Comment: @MarcB $_SESSION works to get the variable in php but not in javascript. I want to access using that.

Comment: php executes on the server, javascript executes on the client. you cannot have PHP access a JS varaible because they are in COMPLETELY different execution environments, and different execution times as well.

Comment: @Michael and Thomas I did try that as per the code shown in the question itself. It didn't work.

Comment: @n00b I did use JSON.parse but turned out no output was shown

Answer (score 0):

You need to `echo` the json:

```
var jsarray= <?php echo json_encode($array1); ?>;
```

Online sample [here](http://pastebin.com/qhRgTiPD).

Answer (score 0):

If i write

```
$array = [1, 2, 3];
print('<script> jsarray = ' . json_encode($array) . ';</script>');
```

then I can access `jsarray` in my javascript.

Note that `jsarray[2]` wil return the 3rd index, not the 2nd (indices start at 0).
You can also check your javascript console (F12 on Chrome + Firefox, then select console tab) for errors.

Answer (score -1):

try this way:

```
<script>
var jsArray = ["<?php echo join("\", \"", $array1); ?>"];
alert(jsArray);
</script>
```

That should work

Comment: bad bad BAD idea. You never dump text from php directly into a JS context. You use json_encode(), always. One JS metacharacter anywhere in the PHP output and you introduce a JS syntax error which completely kills the `<script>` block.